# Apache Flink: Skewed data distribution on KeyedStream

Tags: parallel-processing, apache-flink, flink-streaming, windowing

I have this Java code in Flink:

```
env.setParallelism(6);

//Read from Kafka topic with 12 partitions
DataStream<String> line = env.addSource(myConsumer);

//Filter half of the records 
DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> line_Num_Odd = line_Num.filter(new FilterOdd());
DataStream<Tuple3<String, String, Integer>> line_Num_Odd_2 = line_Num_Odd.map(new OddAdder());

//Filter the other half
DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> line_Num_Even = line_Num.filter(new FilterEven());
DataStream<Tuple3<String, String, Integer>> line_Num_Even_2 = line_Num_Even.map(new EvenAdder());

//Join all the data again
DataStream<Tuple3<String, String, Integer>> line_Num_U = line_Num_Odd_2.union(line_Num_Even_2);

//Window
DataStream<Tuple3<String, String, Integer>> windowedLine_Num_U_K = line_Num_U
                .keyBy(1)
                .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(10)))
                .reduce(new Reducer());
```

The problem is that the window should be able to process with parallelism = 2 as there are two diferent groups of data with keys "odd" and "even" in the second String in the Tuple3. Everything is running with parallelism 6 but not the window which is running with parallelism = 1 and I just need it to have parallelism = 2 because of my requirements.

The functions used in the code are the following:

```
public static class FilterOdd implements FilterFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>> {

    public boolean filter(Tuple2<String, Integer> line) throws Exception {
        Boolean isOdd = (Long.valueOf(line.f0.split(" ")[0]) % 2) != 0;
        return isOdd;
    }
};


public static class FilterEven implements FilterFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>> {

    public boolean filter(Tuple2<String, Integer> line) throws Exception {
        Boolean isEven = (Long.valueOf(line.f0.split(" ")[0]) % 2) == 0;
        return isEven;
    }
};

public static class OddAdder implements MapFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>, Tuple3<String, String, Integer>> {

    public Tuple3<String, String, Integer> map(Tuple2<String, Integer> line) throws Exception {
        Tuple3<String, String, Integer> newLine = new Tuple3<String, String, Integer>(line.f0, "odd", line.f1);
        return newLine;
    }
};


public static class EvenAdder implements MapFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>, Tuple3<String, String, Integer>> {

    public Tuple3<String, String, Integer> map(Tuple2<String, Integer> line) throws Exception {
        Tuple3<String, String, Integer> newLine = new Tuple3<String, String, Integer>(line.f0, "even", line.f1);
        return newLine;
    }
};

public static class Reducer implements ReduceFunction<Tuple3<String, String, Integer>> {

    public Tuple3<String, String, Integer> reduce(Tuple3<String, String, Integer> line1,
            Tuple3<String, String, Integer> line2) throws Exception {
        Long sum = Long.valueOf(line1.f0.split(" ")[0]) + Long.valueOf(line2.f0.split(" ")[0]);
        Long sumTS = Long.valueOf(line1.f0.split(" ")[1]) + Long.valueOf(line2.f0.split(" ")[1]);
        Tuple3<String, String, Integer> newLine = new Tuple3<String, String, Integer>(String.valueOf(sum) +
                " " + String.valueOf(sumTS), line1.f1, line1.f2 + line2.f2);
        return newLine;
    }
};
```

Thanks for your help!

**SOLUTION: I have changed the content of the keys from "odd" and "even" to "odd0000" and "even1111" and it is working properly now.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keys are distributed to worker threads by hash partitioning. This means that the key values are hashed and the thread is determined by modulo #workers. With two keys and two threads there is a good chance that both keys are assigned to the same thread.

You can try to use different key values whose hash values distribute across both threads.

Comment: Thanks!! I have changed it from "odd"/"even" to "odd0000"/"even1111" and it is working now :D. The only thing is that I have two workers and both threads are in the same machine, is there any way to force to put each thread in different workers?

Comment: This depends on your setup. You can start workers with a single slot, but depending on whether you run on YARN, Mesos, or something else, you no control where the workers are started.

Comment: I am running Standalone mode. Yes I have thought about one task slot but i would like to have some performance..hahah I will leave it like this but the throughput is been limited by one of the two workers :(